# Delphi Dois métodos para OnMessage

Tags: delphi, eventos

No Delphi, é possível setar dois métodos para o evento `OnMessage` do `TApplication`?

Detalhe: os dois devem funcionar simultaneamente.

Ex.:

```
TApplication.OnMessage := MetodoA();
TApplication.OnMessage := MetodoB();
```

Answer (score 3):

Em Delphi não é possível atribuir mais de um método para o mesmo evento. Uma forma de burlar essa deficiência é fazer um `MetodoAB()` e referencia-lo no evento:

```
procedure MetodoAB();
begin
  MetodoA();
  MetodoB();
end;

TApplication.OnMessage := MetodoAB();
```

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível, já que as propriedades de evento normalmente são uma procedure of object, que basicamente é um ponteiro para o método. Você pode criar um terceiro método que chame os dois primeiros e atribuir este no evento.